# getting test failed on typing command npm test

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am getting an error which in turns return test failed. Not able to find out the solution to it. Have checked but did not found an appropriate answer for it

I have tried following things:
1. Check babel version :using 7.5.5
2. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/977
3. https://gist.github.com/iamvery/4d4b0ef68cd1f2de81b858fe3a2d08c5
4. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2579

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import connectStyle, { clearThemeCache } from "./src/connectStyle";

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/native-base/src/index.js:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        2.022s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Actual result is test failed as have shown above

Expected result is test should pass

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your jest config file

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [ "node_modules/(?!react-native|@shoutem|react-clone-referenced-element|native-base-shoutem-theme)" ]
```